# Desencriptar oración según lenguaje ingresado

Tags: python

Tengo que realizar un juego en el cual el usuario ingresa una oración, y esa oración se va a encriptar con varios lenguajes, y el objetivo es que esa persona después la desencripte. Ej.: si la frase le sale "Hopolapa copomopo epestapas" es decir *geringoso*, el usuario tenga una lista de lenguajes, y si pone *geringoso* le traduce la oración. La consulta es cómo hacer para insertarle los distintos "lenguajes". Hice uno muy simple para tener de ejemplo:

```
    caracter_elegido= "X"

def encriptar(frase,caracter):
    frase_encriptada =""
    for letra in frase:
        if letra.lower() in "aeiou":
            if letra.isupper():
                frase_encriptada = frase_encriptada + caracter.upper()
            else:
                frase_encriptada = frase_encriptada + caracter
        else:
            frase_encriptada = frase_encriptada + letra
    return frase_encriptada

while True:
    print(encriptar(input("Ingrese frase a encriptar: \n"),caracter_elegido))
    print("\n Ingrese\n(1) para encriptar otra frase")
    print("(2) para finalizar")
    opcion = input(">")
    if opcion == "2":
        print("Finalizado")
        break
```

Comment: Con lenguajes te refieres a idiomas existentes?

Comment: Serian elnguajes de "encriptacion", x ej geringoso, rot13, RLE

Comment: sabes como funciona la encriptacion?

Comment: de donde sacas esos *lenguajes de encriptacion*??

Comment: @Christian claramente es un ejercicio del colegio o la universidad, no están en la parte donde los jugadores usan Diffie Hellman para saludarse. Aunque sea una sobresimplificación, es una forma de criptografía,  literalmente. "escritura escondida"